# Xcode 7 - After Update, UITableView Freezes

Tags: xcode, uitableview, segue, xcode7

I've just updated from Xcode 6 to 7.

I have a UITableview, and when you click on one of the rows, it grabs the data from that that row, and segues into the next viewcontroller and updates the label.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailView"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        //grab row selected and update label on next viewcontroller

        detailViewController *transferVariable = [segue destinationViewController];
        transferVariable.labelName = [arrayOfText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    }

}
```

It was working fine until I update xcode. Now when I click on a row on the UITableview in the IOS simulator, the simulator freezes. It never segues into the next viewcontroller, and there's no error message for me to debug.

How do I go about fixing this?

Thank you

Comment: When it freezes, use the debugger to pause the app.  Check what the threads are doing, especially the main one.

Comment: I have the same issue. Worked perfectly fine until I updated to Xcode 7. Weird thing is I have another UITableView in the same app that is programed very similar that doesn't have any issues. As soon as you press the cell the whole thing freezes and the CPU goes to %100.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm having the same issue after an Xcode 7 update and am having lots of trouble figuring out what's going on. If you or anyone else has any idea what's going on, I'd love to hear! I'll update if I come across a fix

Comment: I submitted a bug report with Apple. I haven't heard from them yet.

Comment: Great, thanks -- I submitted a report as well. If it helps, when I pause the app, the main thread seems to freeze on a [NSString isEqualToString:] call when loading a nib (created on the storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: It's working now

Hey guys, I couldn't figure out what's going on.

Instead, I created a new xcode project and just copy and pasted everything over and built the storyboard again from scratch and it's working normal now.

It's not much of a solution, but my project was small to begin with, but I hope this helps you guys.

Thanks everyone for contributing to this thread.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with Xcode. Unfortunately my project is too big to recreate it easily, but maybe it's my only option.

Comment: I just created new project to upload for the bug report. Copied and pasted everything including the view from the storyboard. Still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. After copying project all tableviews in it are lagging. I think that problem in renaming project. I copied it again, but without renaming(only main folder). And now it works fine. Hope it's helps anyone.